# Spring Integration SFTP Upload non-XML Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, sftp

I have been scouring the internet for ways to setup the sftp outbound gateway using the annotation configuration system. So far I have come up empty.

So is there a way to configure the following XML in the Java code with the help of Spring Annotations?

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                           session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                           request-channel="inbound"
                           command="ls"
                           command-options=""
                           expression="payload"
                           reply-channel="toSplitter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have been adding java config to the manual as time permits.

See [the file section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_7) for an example using the file outbound channel adapter.

For SFTP, the `MessageHandler` is a `FileTransferringMessageHandler` - it needs to be configured with the session factory etc.